# x-editable jQuery-UI throws "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: jquery

I'm using X-editable jQuery-ui version ([x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html)). I have included the CSS and JS (after jQuery-ui) as mentioned in document.

**Code**

```
%a{ "href" => "javascript:void(0)", "id" => "some_id" }
  = "superuser"

:javascript
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#some_id").editable({
        type: 'text',
        pk: 1,
        url: '/some_URL',
        title: 'Enter username'
    });
  });
```

**In View**

When I click on the **superuser** link it throws me following error in console

**Error Details** (inside widget.js)

```
this.options = $.widget.extend( {},

------> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function <------

this.options,
this._getCreateOptions(),
options );
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I might be facing a similar one. Thanks!

Comment: @Ozk Now I'm using **jQuery (+ poshytip plugin)** library, as still I could not get any solution for **jQuery-ui** library

Comment: @Abhi Could you share your solution for jQuery + poshytip?

Comment: @CraigLondon Sorry I don't remember that code anymore, I had this requirement a long time back

Comment: @Abhi No problem!  Thanks for the response anyways!   I think the instructions are missing a reference to PoshyTip and only tell the user to include the CSS and JS file by X-Editable.   I got the jQueryUI version working, you have to use an older version of jQueryUI 1.10.0.